# How to handle versioning of the app in JMVC/Can.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascriptmvc

After you build the app, JMVC generates production.js and production.css. In case you want to set version numbers to avoid the user using the cached files, how do you do that? Eg., producing production.1.1.js and production.1.1.css or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really something you should be doing with your build process, not steal. Rename the file after it is generated.

Comment: but renaming the file will break the links in other files, right? Which would mean to change the reference to this particular file on other files manually.

Comment: There is only 1 file: production.js. No other files would reference it.